# Prepare statement filling

Tags: php, mysql, oop, prepared-statement

so i'm trying to make one class (for mysqli operations) as much reusable for other classes (which use different tables and parameters) as possible. A fragment from main class:

```
class sql
{
    private $sql;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sql = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
        if ($this->sql->connect_errno > 0)
        {
            die('Unable to connect to database: ' .$this->sql->connect_error);
        }
        elseif (!$this->sql->set_charset("utf8"))
        {
            printf('Error loading character set utf8: ' .$this->sql->error);
        }
    }
    public function newEntry($table, $entryString, $valueString, $typeString, $dataString)
    {
        $statement = $this->sql->prepare("INSERT INTO $table($entryString) VALUES ($valueString)");
        $statement->bind_param($typeString, $dataString);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->close();
        $this->sql->close();
    }
}
```

and here is my other class, in which i'm trying to pass variables to main function newEntry():

```
class user extends sql
{
    protected $table = 'foo';

    public function newUser($name, $surname)
    {
        $entryString = 'name, surname';
        $valueString = '?, ?';
        $typeString = 'ss';
        $dataString = '$name, $surname';
        parent::newEntry($this->table, $entryString, $valueString, $typeString, $dataString);
    }
}
```

so when i'm trying to execute this, i get a "Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in..". I understand it's because my $dataString acts like a single entry: "John, Doe". Is there a way to make it act like numerous separate params instead of just a string?

Comment: Why are you wrapping mysqli in the first place? Also why are you setting up a new connection everything you create an instance of a random class? And considering this is tagged oop why would a user be an sql?

Comment: On your $dataString assignment you are using single quotes. If you want the value to be the parameter values you would want to use the double quotes.

Comment: @Cameron nah this doesn't work either. However i found  the solution - `call_user_func_array`